# Access a 2D array from another class

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to improve current code. To do so, I want to call another class.

I have colours and fruit, essentially something like this:
red = apple, yellow = banana, orange = orange ...

My proposed solution is to put this into a matrix, have the colour from one class and call the other class to get back the fruit name. Here is what I have so far:

```
private String c1 = red 
... 

private String f1 = apple
...

private String[][] food;

public void setFood(){
// HELP NEEDED 
} 

public String getFruit(string colour){
// HELP NEEDED - I'm guessing some sort of 2 for loops ?

return fruit; 
}
```

Comment: Also confused on how to grab the fruit from one class by giving it the colour

Comment: You should use an instance of a `java.util.Map` for this

Comment: There is too little code here for us to be able to evaluate.

Comment: But, why a 2D array? Why not have a `class` where the name of the fruit (or food) is one attribute, and the color another? `new Fruit ("Granny Smith Apple", "Green")`, `new Fruit ("Navel Orange", "Orange")`, ?   What about using `enum` for colours?

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong with a 2D array necessarily, but we need to know the problem you are trying to solve.